# Filtrar resultados por rango de fechas

Tags: jquery, laravel

Estoy haciendo una web de reservas de casas por vacaciones, en la web hay una página donde puedo realizar búsqueda de casas por ciudad y por rango de fechas.

**Mi tabla casas**

| id | casa | precio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Casa 1 | 250 |
| 2 | Casa 2 | 560 |

**Mi tabla orders**

| id | casa_id | fecha_entrada | fecha_salida |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-12-05 | 2022-12-10 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-12-12 | 2022-12-16 |

He realizado la programación de esta página en jQuery, para ir obteniendo los resultados a través de AJAX, entonces cuando le pulso al botón de "buscar_escapada":

```
$('#buscar_escapada').click(function(){
    var fechaEntrada = moment($("#date_start2").val());
    var fechaSalida = moment($("#date_end2").val());
    fechaINI = fechaEntrada._i;
    fechaFIN = fechaSalida._i;
    //Obtengo los valores de entrada y salida que elige el cliente
    filtrar();
    //Esto llama a una funciona llamada filtrar() donde ya consulto por AJAX
});
```

**Function filtrar()**

```
  function filtrar(){ 
    ciudad=document.getElementById('ciudad').value;
    
    var url = '/filtrar-escapada';
    
    $.ajax({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            'ciudad' : ciudad,
            'casa_id' : casa,
            'fechaINI': fechaINI,
            'fechaFIN': fechaFIN
        },
        success: function(resultado){
         //Aquí imprimo el resultado
        }
    });
   }
```

La ruta `/filtrar-escapada` va a mi controlador para filtrar el resultado de busqueda.

```
public function filtrarEscapada(Request $request)
{
$casas = Casas::query()->with('galeria','resenas')->withCount('resenas', 'habitaciones')->where('estado', 1);
  if(!empty($request->ciudad))
  {
    $casas->where('ciudad_id', $ciudad->id);
  }
  //En esta parte intento que si esa casa está reservada en esas fechas no mostrarla, pero no lo consigo
  if(!empty($request->fechaINC && $request->fechaFIN))
  {
    $escapada->join('orders', 'casa_id', $request->casa_id)->where('orders.fecha_entrada','>=',$request->fechaINC)->where('orders.fecha_salida','<=',$request->fechaFIN);
  }
    $casas = $casas->get(); 
}
```

La idea es comprobar, si el rengo de fechas que introduce el cliente existe alguna coincidencia con la casa y el rango de fechas que esta en la tabla `orders` no mostrar esa casa, ya que no esta disponible.

Pero no consigo hacerlo, alguna sugerencia??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera cosa que te recomendaría es hacer una revisión de la consulta SQL que estás haciendo. Esto puede ayudarte a detectar si hay algún error en la sintaxis o en el uso de las condiciones que estás estableciendo.

En cuanto a la consulta en sí, creo que hay algunos problemas con la forma en que estás construyéndola. Por ejemplo, estás haciendo una unión de las tablas casas y orders en la línea:

```
$escapada->join('orders', 'casa_id', $request->casa_id)
```

El problema es que esta unión no tiene sentido, ya que estás usando la columna casa_id como si fuera el identificador de la tabla orders. Sin embargo, en la tabla orders, la columna casa_id se refiere al identificador de una casa específica, no del conjunto de casas en general.

Para resolver este problema, te recomendaría que utilices una subconsulta en la cláusula WHERE de tu consulta. De esta manera, puedes buscar las casas que no están reservadas en un rango de fechas específico, y luego mostrar sólo esas casas en tu resultado.

Algo así como esto:

```
$casas->whereNotExists(function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->from('orders')
          ->whereColumn('orders.casa_id', 'casas.id')
          ->where('orders.fecha_entrada', '>=', $request->fechaINC)
          ->where('orders.fecha_salida', '<=', $request->fechaFIN);
});
```

Este código utiliza la función whereNotExists para buscar las casas que no tienen una reserva en el rango de fechas especificado. La subconsulta se encarga de encontrar todas las reservas en la tabla orders que coinciden con las condiciones que estableces, y luego se excluyen esas casas del resultado final.

Para coincidir ambas fechas en un unico día lo que puedes hacer es modificar la condición de la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
if(!empty($request->fechaINC && $request->fechaFIN))
        {
          $casas->whereDoesntHave('orders', function($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where(function($q) use ($request) {
              $q->where('fecha_entrada', '>=', $request->fechaINC)
                ->where('fecha_entrada', '<', $request->fechaFIN);
            })->orWhere(function($q) use ($request) {
              $q->where('fecha_salida', '>', $request->fechaINC)
                ->where('fecha_salida', '<=', $request->fechaFIN);
            })->orWhere(function($q) use ($request) {
              $q->where('fecha_entrada', '<=', $request->fechaINC)
                ->where('fecha_salida', '>=', $request->fechaFIN);
            });
          });
        }
```

De esta manera, se filtrarán las casas que tienen una reserva que se superponga en algún momento con el rango de fechas indicado. Esto incluye el caso en el que la reserva coincide con un solo día.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta tan rápida y elaborada, supongo que tengo que substuir `$escapada->join('orders', 'casa_id', $request->casa_id)->where('o...` por tu código no??

Comment: Intentalo y me cuentas como te funciono.

Comment: Si, ya lo probe, pero reserve una casa en fechas proximas y poniendo los intervalos de fecha, me sigue mostrando una casa que esta reservada

Comment: Vale habia un campo que estaba mal, es `$request->fechaINI` en lugar de `$request->fechaINC`. Pero en este caso si la fecha de entrada y salida coinciden no muestra esa casa, pero hay que tener en cuenta que puede coincidir en un unico día, y eso es suficiente para no mostrar esa casa

Comment: Es como si solo tuviese en cuenta la fecha de inicio

Comment: verifica la actualizacion haber si te funciona

Comment: Algo raro hay, porque me desactiva otras casas tambien, parece ser casas que tienen alguna reserva pero la fecha no corresponde tampoco @AlejandroGonzalez

Comment: haber intenta nuevamente con el codigo nuevo que publique.

Comment: Ahora si que está estupendo!!! Aunq me surge una duda, por ejemplo estoy probando con una casa que he reservaso desde el 14 a la 16 de este mes. En la busqueda me aparece como disponible si escojo como ultimo día el 14 o bien si empiezo el 16, eso no deberia ser así no?

Comment: uhm ya veo podrias intentar con between,                                                                     if (!empty($request->fechaINC && $request->fechaFIN)) {
    $casas->whereDoesntHave('orders', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where(function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereBetween('fecha_entrada', [$request->fechaINC, $request->fechaFIN])
                ->orWhereBetween('fecha_salida', [$request->fechaINC, $request->fechaFIN]);
        });
    });
}